# Rails new Method works in console, fails in controller and browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to invoke a .new on the following model:

```
class Callback < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
    has_one :servicetime 
end
```

I can call this method with no issue from my console, however within a separate controller for my customers it is telling me that I have the "Wrong number of arguments" and errors out.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how one might go about researching what would cause something to behave so differently in the console than the controller / browser?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Good thought, all my migrations are up.

Comment: @Anthony He would have seen a migration pending message straight away after attempting to connect to the application. We need to see customer.rb, as well as the full error message.

Comment: Can you provide some more information on how you're invoking the .new call?   Is it simply 'Callback.new'?

Comment: @Agazoom just Callback.new for the moment. I plan to pass all the params through the method, I just want to get it to create an empty callback to start. This works for other models in my app, not this one. Also, as described, this works from the console.

Comment: Make sure it's the right `Callback`.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you tried restarting your web app?

Comment: @creativereason - Yup. and my Mac. Good Thought.

Comment: @DaveNewton - What do you mean by the right ``callback`` ?

Comment: I'm guessing you should just go ahead and post your controller code just to make sure you didn't miss anything / typo, etc.

Comment: Show us the stracktrace for the issue please.

Comment: I mean make sure it's the class you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but you might have a **name collision with "Callback"** since the very same word is used as a ruby/rails callback. Try to rename the model to "MyCallback" or similar.

=> Just experienced something similar with a model by the name of "Case". Also very strange behaviour.

Comment: Ben, you were exactly right. I renamed my Callback to Retreat and everything functions perfectly. You are a lifesaver. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, I don't see anything wrong here. Should check controller on your customers for sure all thing are correct.